# Resolve Fatal signal 11(SIGSEV) at 0x00000000

Tags: java, android, android-intent, out-of-memory, fatal-error

I have problem with test my application on Galaxy S3 device. I created the apk file and put it in to Galaxy S2 and It works but when I put my application in Galaxy S3 I obtain this error:

Resolve Fatal signal 11(SIGSEV) at 0x00000000

This is the Activity's code:

```
public class Livello extends Activity {
    private TextView live;
    private TextView motto;
    private TextView punteggio;
    private int score=0;
    @Override


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_livello);
            int i=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("livello");
            int livello=0;  


    RelativeLayout rel=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.provaLayout);
            rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marrone);
            Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(),"chu.otf");   


        switch (i) {
        case 1:
            live=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.livello);
            motto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.motto);
            punteggio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggio);
            live.setText("LIVELLO 1");
            live.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            live.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            live.refreshDrawableState();
            motto.setText(R.string.mottoLivello1);
            motto.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            motto.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            motto.refreshDrawableState();
            punteggio.setText("PUNTEGGIO: "+0);
            punteggio.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            punteggio.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            punteggio.refreshDrawableState();
            livello=1;
            new PassaActivity().execute(livello);
            break;
        case 2:
            live=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.livello);
            motto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.motto);
            punteggio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggio);
            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live.setText("LIVELLO 2");
            live.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            live.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            live.refreshDrawableState();
            motto.setText(R.string.mottoLivello2);
            motto.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            motto.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            motto.refreshDrawableState();
            punteggio.setText("PUNTEGGIO: "+score);
            punteggio.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            punteggio.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            punteggio.refreshDrawableState();
            livello=2;
            new PassaActivity().execute(livello);
            break;
        case 3:
            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.livello);
            motto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.motto);
            punteggio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggio);
            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live.setText("LIVELLO 3");
            live.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            live.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            live.refreshDrawableState();
            motto.setText(R.string.mottoLivello3);
            motto.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            motto.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            motto.refreshDrawableState();
            punteggio.setText("PUNTEGGIO: "+score);
            punteggio.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            punteggio.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            punteggio.refreshDrawableState();
            livello=3;
            new PassaActivity().execute(livello);
            break;
        case 4:

            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.livello);
            motto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.motto);
            punteggio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggio);
            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live.setText("LIVELLO 4");
            live.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            live.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            live.refreshDrawableState();
            motto.setText(R.string.mottoLivello4);
            motto.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            motto.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            motto.refreshDrawableState();
            punteggio.setText("PUNTEGGIO: "+score);
            punteggio.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            punteggio.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            punteggio.refreshDrawableState();
            livello=4;
            new PassaActivity().execute(livello);
            break;
        case 5:

            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.livello);
            motto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.motto);
            punteggio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggio);
            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live.setText("LIVELLO 5");
            live.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            live.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            live.refreshDrawableState();
            motto.setText(R.string.mottoLivello5);
            motto.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            motto.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            motto.refreshDrawableState();
            punteggio.setText("PUNTEGGIO: "+score);
            punteggio.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            punteggio.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            punteggio.refreshDrawableState();
            livello=5;
            new PassaActivity().execute(livello);
            break;
        case 6:

            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.livello);
            motto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.motto);
            punteggio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggio);
            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live.setText("LIVELLO 6");
            live.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            live.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            live.refreshDrawableState();
            motto.setText(R.string.mottoLivello6);
            motto.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            motto.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            motto.refreshDrawableState();
            punteggio.setText("PUNTEGGIO: "+score);
            punteggio.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            punteggio.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            punteggio.refreshDrawableState();
            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            livello=6;
            new PassaActivity().execute(livello);
            break;
        case 7:

            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.livello);
            motto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.motto);
            punteggio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggio);
            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live.setText("LIVELLO 7");
            live.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            live.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            live.refreshDrawableState();
            motto.setText(R.string.mottoLivello7);
            motto.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            motto.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            motto.refreshDrawableState();
            punteggio.setText("PUNTEGGIO: "+score);
            punteggio.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            punteggio.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            punteggio.refreshDrawableState();
            livello=7;
            new PassaActivity().execute(livello);
            break;
        case 8:

            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.livello);
            motto=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.motto);
            punteggio=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.punteggio);
            score=getIntent().getExtras().getInt("punteggio");
            live.setText("LIVELLO 8");
            live.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            live.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            live.refreshDrawableState();
            motto.setText(R.string.mottoLivello8);
            motto.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            motto.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            motto.refreshDrawableState();
            punteggio.setText("PUNTEGGIO: "+score);
            punteggio.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
            punteggio.setTypeface(myTypeface);
            punteggio.refreshDrawableState();
            livello=8;
            new PassaActivity().execute(livello);
            break;
        }
    }

    class PassaActivity extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>{
        Intent i=null;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Codice corretto per l'applicazione ma per muovermi devo evitare queste cose
//          i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Gioca.class);
//          i.putExtra("livello",params[0]);
//          i.putExtra("punteggio",score);
//          Log.i("valore",String.valueOf(params[0]));
//          startActivity(i);

//          //Codice per andare più veloce tra attività
            i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Punteggio.class);
            i.putExtra("livello",params[0]);
            i.putExtra("punteggio",2000);
            Log.i("valore",String.valueOf(params[0]));
            startActivity(i);

            return null;

        }

        public Void onPosteExecture(Void v){

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in,R.anim.slide_on);
            return v;
        }




    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.livello, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and the xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/provaLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Livello" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativoUno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/livello"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Livello"
            android:textSize="50sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/motto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/relativoUno"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativoUno"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/motto"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/punteggio"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone can help me?
The error appear at:
rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marrone);

Comment: Your code is very inefficient :$

Comment: This is because of the vortex heap space dump. Fixed by creating multiple pointers to SIGSEGV.

Comment: Great that you've included your code and xml, but asking for help with an Android crash should always include your relevant logcat output -- then again, if you look at that yourself, you'll probably be told of the exact source and line number that led to the crash (though you'll have to pick out of a list).

Comment: thanks for answer..@mah the lines of code that generate this error is rel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.marrone);